# C# Linq Join がVisual Studio 2017, 2019で動きが違うか。

Tags: c#

ご教授よろしくおねがいします。

C#のLinqでJoinを行う際に第3引数のインテリセンスが働きません。
これはVisual Studio 2017では以下のコードでp.と入力したあとにCountryID, Nameが選択できるはずですが、Visual Studio 2019ではインテリセンスに表示されません。
.NET Frameworksは4.6を利用しています。
Visual Studioのバージョンによってこのような差異があるのでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 確かに2017/2019によって動作が違うようですね。IDE右上の「フィードバックの送信」から報告・問い合わせしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 2017の時も出てから暫くはそんな感じでした。2019になってからも細かく挙動が変わってますが、今(Version 16.4.3)が一番やな感じですね。

Comment: 皆様、ありがとうございます。フィードバック送信しました！ ひとまず2017使います。。