# C# ラムダ式の引数の型が違う

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Windows10 1909
Visual Studio Community 2019 16.5.4 にて
.NET Core 3.1 C# コンソールアプリケーション プロジェクトを作成、
Program.csに以下のコードを書きました。

```csharp
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyStruct[] a = new MyStruct[10];
            /*
             * aへの何らかの処理
             */
            Array.Sort(a, (x, y) => x.$$ );
        }
    }

    struct MyStruct
    {
        public int I;
    }
}
```

現在は13行目の`Array.Sort(a, (x, y) => x.`を入力し、$$の位置にカーソルがある状態です。

起こってほしいこと

- 入力候補としてMyStructのメンバが表示。

実際に起きたこと

- MyStructのメンバが入力候補に表示されず、別のクラス(恐らくArray)のメンバが入力候補として表示される。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Visual Studio 2019でMyStructのメンバを表示させるにはどのようにすればいいですか?

Intellisenseを使わずに`Array.Sort(a, (x, y) => x.I.CompareTo(y.I));`と入力してもコンパイルエラーは出ませんでした。

試したこと

表示された

- Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.22を使用
- ReSharper 2020.1 EAP8をインストール

表示されない

- .NET Framework 4.7.2を使う
- 新規プロジェクトを作成
- Visual StudioをVisual Studio Installerからアンインストール->再インストール

Comment: これと類似かもしれませんね。[C# Linq Join がVisual Studio 2017, 2019で動きが違うか。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62458/26370) 同様に「フィードバックの送信」とかしてみたらどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif 素早いコメントありがとうございます。頂いたリンク先と同じもののようです。Developer Communityで関連する報告を見つけたのでvoteしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kunif氏のコメント

> これと類似かもしれませんね。[C# Linq Join がVisual Studio 2017, 2019で動きが違うか。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62458/26370) 同様に「フィードバックの送信」とかしてみたらどうでしょう？

を頂きDeveloper Communityで検索したところ、類似した問題を見つけ、voteしました。
[Intellisense not precisely in LINQ method Syntax "Join"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/638094/intellisense-not-precisely-in-linq-method-syntax-j.html)
[Intellisense not working properly witch 'join' of linq](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/734638/intellisense-not-working-properly-witch-join-of-li.html)

Under Consideration になっているのでバージョンが上がれば解決すると思われます。

現状では Visual Studio 2017等別のIDEを使うことで解決します。

kunifさんありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

＞Visual Studio 2019でMyStructのメンバを表示させるにはどのようにすればいいですか?
に回答

```
Array.Sort(a, (x, y) => x.I.CompareTo(y.I));
```

ではなく

```
Array.Sort<MyStruct>(a, (x, y) => x.I.CompareTo(y.I));
```

と 型を明示すると インテリセンスが効くようですね。

`Array.Sort` の部分は ジェネリックメソッドになっていて
`Array.Sort<T>(T[] array, Comparison<T> comparison)` なので `T` の型が `MyStruct` 
だよと明示的に教えてあげるといいみたいです。

```
a = a.OrderBy(r => r.I).ToArray();
```

なんて書く事もできます。
struct の場合は 無駄なコピーが多そうですが・・。